# PowerShell send SMTP email without (default) authentication

Tags: authentication, powershell, smtp

I am attempting to deliver an email to an Exchange-server using PowerShell. My goal is to use plain old SMTP to deliver a message to a local user (mailbox) on the Exchange-server. The Exchange-server is located within the same network and AD-domain as the sending server and as the logged on sending user.

However the user I am sending from does not have access to send emails on that Exchange-server. And PowerShell seems to send authentication using the logged on user credentials by default.

```
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("exchangeserver.mylan") 
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $message)
```

I have tried to add `$smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = $false` before the `$smtp.Send(...` line without success.

One solution would be to allow this user to send messages on the Exchange server. However the user will change depending on what service is running this script, so I don't want to solve it that way.

Another solution would be to hardcode credentials using something like `$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("DOMAIN\user", "password")` (also before `$smtp.Send(...` line). I've had no luck in this either.

The solution I'd really like is to just send email in PowerShell anonymously using good old auth free SMTP.

Comment: What version of Exchange are you running? Can the script be run from the Exchange server?

Comment: Not sure of what Exchange version is running (and shouldn't be relevant). Scripts can't be run from Exchange server. High security environment so there is very little to be done except to get it to work. :)

Comment: Exchange servers don't do anonymous relay by default (at least not since 5.5).  If you want this to work doing an anonymous relay using a Receive Connector, it's going to have to be fixed at the server.  If the script is run on the Exchange server, you can use localhost, bypassing the Receive Connector permissions.

Comment: Don't want relay, want local delivery (end of line for message).

Comment: If you're doing SMTP to another SMTP server that's going to do the delivery for you, or send it on to some other server that will, that's a relay.

Comment: Correct, but I only want to deliver directly to internal server. However PowerShell does auth with logged in user by default, and logged in user doesn't have access to deliver. So my goal is to simply tell PowerShell not to auth.

Comment: Problem was solved by having a user with send rights run script, but if anyone can answer the question it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create new Receive Connector
2) Enable anonymous authentication on it
3) Lock it down to IP address of the computer you are running the script on

Comment: Thanks, but need to solve it on the client side, not the server side.

Comment: @Tedd - if your server does not accept anon connections there is nothing you can do on client side other than changing current configuration or using another server :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but I'm surprised there isn't an answer here for this. I was confused initially because I have some similar code I wrote in C# and it works just fine. It seems PowerShell will default to using someone's credentials. I won't assume it's who runs the script, but it could be.

When I'm building up the credential object, I pass in a space for the username and password and that seems to work fine.

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (" ", " ")
```

If I completely leave out the credential part then it will use someone's credentials or something. Until now I was getting the following message:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
```

I hope this helps someone with such an odd problem.